# Assign to union type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
interface Data {
    [key: string]: number
}

interface MetaData {
    date: Date
}

export type Datapoint = MetaData & Data
```

so far so good. The problem comes when I need to make one of these:

```
const d: Datapoint = {date: new Date()}

-> error TS2322: Type '{ date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'Datapoint'.
  Type '{ date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
    Property 'dd' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Note that's an *intersection* type, not a union type (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). If it was a union type (`MetaData | Data`) you'd be OK, but you cannot make something that's both `MetaData` *and* `Data` given their definitions (as the `date` property cannot be both a `number` and a `Date`).

Comment: There is no way to describe what you want in TypeScript. Indexed type `{ [key: string]: number}` means that each and every property must have `number` type, there is no provision for something like "but if a property name is `date` it must be a `Date`, not `number`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to assign to a union type, then we need to create a union type in the first place. In your question, you were creating an intersection type.

- Union types use the `|` operator and represent "a value that can be one of several types."
- Intersection types use the `&` operator and combine "multiple types into one."

Once we have a union type, we assign to it using one of the several types that it represents.

Here is [an example union type assignment in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MetaData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20date%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20creates%20a%20union%20type.%20%20%20%20%0D%0Atype%20Datapoint%20%3D%20MetaData%20%7C%20Data%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20assigns%20to%20it%20with%20the%20MetaData%20type%0D%0Alet%20someMetaData%3A%20Datapoint%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20date%3A%20new%20Date()%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20assigns%20to%20it%20with%20the%20Data%20type%0D%0Alet%20someData%3A%20Datapoint%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22foo%22%3A%2012376%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%22bar%22%3A%2011233%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%22baz%22%3A%2072343%0D%0A%7D%3B).

```
interface Data {
  [key: string]: number;
}

interface MetaData {
  date: Date;
}

// This creates a union type.    
type Datapoint = MetaData | Data; 

// This assigns to it with the MetaData type
let someMetaData: Datapoint = {
  date: new Date()
};

// This assigns to it with the Data type
let someData: Datapoint = {
  "foo": 12376, 
  "bar": 11233, 
  "baz": 72343
};
```

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html